# Upload image to site and facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I need to upload an image to my site for storage, plus upload to facebook as well, hopefully in one process.  I've found the FB api for uploading to fb using their own dialogs, but that won't do because I need it on my server too.  I'm thinking that maybe uploading to my server first, then using the FB API to upload to FB.  How would one handle the authentication on the server side?  Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Does your website have any database? If so, only insert images into it.

Comment: It's bad practice to store images in a database, even though it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to upload it to the server and then to Facebook is quite possible. Authenticate against the Facebook server client-side then send the picture and OAuth token to the server.
Save the picture on your server then use the OAuth token to upload it onto the Facebook server.